# Pandas Dataframe groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset that looks similar to this:

| Name | Status | Activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | student | yes |
| John | businessman | yes |
| Elle | student | no |
| Chris | policeman | yes |
| John | businessman | no |
| Clay | businessman | yes |

I want to group the dataset by `Status` and `Name` which have `Activity` as a 'yes' and count the `Name`. If it at least has one 'yes', it will be counted.

Basically, this is **the output that I want**:

student  1  Jane

businessman  2  John, Clay

policeman  1  Chris

I've tried these codes:

```
cb = (DataFrame.groupby(['Name', 'Status']).sum(DataFrame['Activity'].eq('yes')))

cb = (DataFrame.groupby(['Name', 'Status']).any(DataFrame['Activity'].eq('yes')))

cb = (DataFrame.groupby(['Name', 'Status']).nunique(DataFrame['Activity'].eq('yes')))
```

but, all of them give this error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Please help me to fix this code. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
data = {'Name': {0: 'Jane', 1: 'John', 2: 'Elle', 3: 'Chris', 4: 'John', 5: 'Clay'},
        'Status': {0: 'student', 1: 'businessman', 2: 'student', 3: 'policeman', 4: 'businessman', 5: 'businessman'},
        'Activity': {0: 'yes', 1: 'yes', 2: 'no', 3: 'yes', 4: 'no', 5: 'yes'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

**Code**

```
out = (df[df['Activity'].eq('yes')]
       .groupby('Status', sort=False)['Name'].agg(['count', ', '.join]))
```

`out`

```
            count   join
Status      
student     1       Jane
businessman 2       John, Clay
policeman   1       Chris
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works well, but why does when I deploy this code to the real data, it counts the activity number, while I want the number of distinct names that have activity as a yes?

Comment: It's my job to solve the examples and yours to put them into your dataset. It is not difficult to get your output using solution. For various reasons, I only solve examples and do not take additional questions. The following function will help you https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html

Answer (score 1):

Check below:

```
dd = df.query("Activity != 'no'").\
groupby('Status').\
agg({'Name':[','.join,'count']}).reset_index()

dd.columns = ['Status','Names','count']

dd.head()
```

Output:

[image]